# How to pass optional elements to a component as a prop in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am trying to figure out the proper "react" way to pass in an optional prop that is an Element to a container component, that is handled differently from the children of that component.

For a simple example, I have a Panel component, which renders its children, that also has an optional "title" prop (which is an element rather than a string, for the sake of the example) that gets specially rendered (put in a special spot, with special behaviors in  while maintaining the abstraction.

One option is to have a  component which is pulled out of the children and rendered specially:

```
<Panel>
   <Title> some stuff</Title>
   <div> some other stuff</div>
</Panel>
```

But it seems wierd to have the children pulled out and handled separately like that.

How is this normally handled in react, and am I even thinking about this the right way

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special. Just pass the title component as a prop, and then use `{this.props.title}` wherever you want it to be rendered:

```
class Panel extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.props.title}
      <div>Some other stuff...</div>
    </div>;
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var title = <Title>My Title</Title>;
    return <Panel title={title}/>;
  }
}
```

If you don't pass any value for the `title` prop (or if the value is `false`, `null`, or `undefined`) then nothing will be rendered there.

This is a fairly common pattern in React.

Comment: ugh, thanks. I was stuck in this view that "title={title}" had to be a primitive type.

Comment: Is it a common react pattern (or even possible) to restrict the title propType to be an actual Title component?

Comment: It's correct in general, but there is exceptions. If the prop contain array that doesn't exist, it will does generate error (that's what I have got in my tests anyway). This :


**<a href={"tel:" + this.props.data.contactDetails [1]}
                    >
                      {this.props.data.contactDetails [1]}</a>**


will generate error if : this.props.data.contactDetails [1] didn't provided.

Answer (score 5):

you can do something like this

```
render(){
    <div>
        {this.props.title ? this.props.title : null}
        {this.props.children}
    </div>
}
```

basically if you pass a title element as a prop then create it as an element and render it. else just put in null...

to create it you would do something like this.

```
<Panel title={<Title>Something Here</Title>}
    <div> something here</div>
</Panel>
```

This is generally how react should handle optional child components

Answer (score 1):

When you need an attribute from your optional `prop`, you will have to **check first** if the `prop` was delivered. Otherwise, you will get a:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'yourPropProperty' of undefined
```

In conditional rendering context (depending on my optional `this.props.ignore` array), this **won't** work:

```js
{!this.props.ignore.includes('div')) && (
   <div>
      Hey
   </div>
)}
```

Instead, you should do:

```js
{(!this.props.ignore || !this.props.ignore.includes('div'))) && (
   <div>
      Hey
   </div>
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is have default props (usually initialised to a no-op) for your component.

For example, if you want to have an optional function prop:

```
class NewComponent extends React.Component {
    ...
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.functionThatDoesSomething()
    }
}

NewComponent.defaultProps = {
    functionThatDoesSomething: () => {}
}
```

This way, parent components can choose to pass the function prop or not and your app won't crash due to the error

> this.props.functionThatDoesSomething is not a function
>   .