# React props optional spread attributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, spread-syntax

I'm trying to provide multiple optional attributes between components in React.

Example:

```
File: GenericCard.js

...
<Reactstrap.CardHeader {...this.props.headerArgs}>{this.props.cardheader}</Reactstrap.CardHeader>
<Reactstrap.CardBody {...this.props.bodyArgs}>{this.props.cardbody}</Reactstrap.CardBody>
<Reactstrap.CardFooter {...this.footerArgs}>{this.props.cardfooter}</Reactstrap.CardFooter>
...
```

I'm passing the props to this component as follow:

```
File: SpecificCard.js

<GenericCard cardheader={header} cardbody={body} cardfooter={footer} {...bodyArgs} />
```

And for example a different variant would be:

```
File: DifferentCard.js

<GenericCard cardheader={header} cardbody={body} cardfooter={footer} {...headerArgs} {...footerArgs} />
```

But such syntax would provide me with:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: {the attribute that's missing} is not defined
```

Meaning, I'd like to be able to pass multiple options for different attributes using spread arguments, and were they to be not defined, I'd like the props to ignore them (as I [understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640327/how-to-pass-optional-elements-to-a-component-as-a-prop-in-reactjs) that is the case for normal props?).

I thought of putting a default value, but I can't seem to find how to achieve that.

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

Edit:

I tried replacing my code as per @SteveTomlin suggestion:

```
File: SpecificCard.js

{...{...headerArgs, ...bodyArgs, cardbody: body, cardheader: header}}
```

After doing some debugging I realized that the issue was that the spread variables were passing the attributes themselves and not the variables, meaning I can't distinguish between the different variables when receiving it on `GenericCard.js`. Explanation in code:

```
File: SpecificCard.js

const body = <div>a</div>;
const bodyArgs = {attributeA: 'a', attributeB: 'b', attributeC: 'c'};
```

When I receive it on `GenericCard.js` the props looks like:

```
cardbody: "<div>a</div>"
attributeA: 'a'
attributeB: 'b'
attributeB: 'c'
```

So I don't have the `bodyArgs` as props but rather its attributes.

I tweaked Steve's suggestion to look like this:

```
{...{headerArgs: headerArgs, bodyArgs: bodyArgs, footerArgs: footerArgs, cardheader:header, cardbody:body, cardfooter:footer}}
```

Which then works fine, but necessitates defining **all** the variables on the parent component, which is not what I was aiming at. What I'm looking for is a way to do exactly that, but without having to define the empty variables (again, as I understood React works in the link above). Something like this should work in the solution just the same as the code above:

```
{...{headerArgs: headerArgs, cardheader:header, cardbody:body, cardfooter:footer}}
```

Can this sort of props behavior work? How can I do that? Shouldn't the child props ignore missing props? If not, can I put default values on the child component?

Comment: do it like this: {...{...headerArgs, ...bodyArgs, cardbody: body, cardheader: header}}

Comment: @SteveTomlin when passing the props or receiving? Because on the receiver side I need to put the props on different parts of the component.

Comment: And on the passing side I need to be able to not specify all the variables (i.e. for it to work even if I'm only sending cardbody, cardheader, cardfooter).

Comment: create it as an object first, adding the properties according to whatever if conditions, then pass the final object to the react component

Comment: @SteveTomlin so you mean whatever the case, I will always need to define all the props in the passing side (even if they will be empty)?

Comment: Also: I now debugged and saw that when passing in such manner (`{...{...headerArgs, ...bodyArgs, cardbody: body, cardheader: header}}`) the spread variables are not being received as props (getting it as for example: `{...this.props.headerArgs}`)

Comment: OK I see the problem now! The transfer destructs my spread variables so if it `bodyArgs={attributes}` in `SpecificCard.js` then when `GenericCard.js` receives it, it only gets the `attributes` as props and not `bodyArgs` as props. Hence, I can't seem to distinguish between the different spread variables because they will all destruct to the attributes. I'll edit that in the post itself.